# Mobile Safari: JS event for jump to last scroll position on refresh

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Is there a Javascript event that I can hook into that fires when the page is *refreshed*, and Safari 'jumps' back to the scroll position you were at?

It's very frustrating, as the `scroll` event only fires on user/touch-induced scrolls, so will not fire in this case. I need to specifically find a way to bind to that event, as `DOMContentLoaded`, for example, fires even before that, and the window's `load` event would fire too late, as that will wait for all content to load.

Reason for this is that I am checking if an element is in view (using `getBoundingClientRect`).

Am I missing something here? As I'm not using jQuery, but vanilla JS, I have no `document.ready()` to try (though judging by the [source code of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery), I doubt it would work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, it turns out that the `load` /`onload` event on the `window` triggers this jump in Safari Mobile (and presumably other browsers too), so binding to that event would suffice.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: It doesn't seem correct, at least this is not what I saw. It looks setting initial scroll position doesn't correlate with load event and can occur after it.